# What's wrong with this php code?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I created a web form to insert data into a mysql database.  I thought I had the php to insert the data from the form nailed, but alas, when I hit submit nothing happened.  I do have the proper hostname and other db details correct, I just didn't post them here.

I probably have multiple errors in this code.  I'm hoping some of the experts can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("hostname","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO games (game_name, release_date, game_category, game_type, game_console)
VALUES
('$_POST[game_name]','$_POST[release_date]','$_POST[game_category]','$_POST[game_type]','$_POST[game_console]')";

mysql_query($sql);

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO trophy_totals (game_name, bronze_ttl, silver_ttl, gold_ttl, plat_ttl, hidden_ttl, total_points)
VALUES
('$_POST[game_name]','$_POST[bronze_ttl]','$_POST[silver_ttl]','$_POST[gold_ttl]','$_POST[plat_ttl]','$_POST[hidden_ttl]','$_POST[total_points]')";

mysql_query($sql2);
?>

<?php
    foreach($_POST['trophy'] as $trophy) {
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO trophies (game_name, tr_name, tr_description, tr_color, tr_ach_value) VALUES ('".$_POST['game_name']."', '".$trophy['name']."', '".$trophy['desc']."', '".$trophy['color']."', '".$trophy['tr_ach_value']."')";
        mysql_query($sql3);
    }
echo "Record added";

mysql_close($con)


?>
```

Is it a problem with my form possibly?

```
<form action="http://www.yeahthatrocks.com/update.php" method="post">
Game Name:  <input name="game_name" type="text" size="25" maxlength="255" /><br></br>
Release Date:  <input name="release_date" type="text" size="25" /><p></p>

<p>Console:
  <select name="game_console">
    <option value="PS3">PS3</option>
    <option value="Xbox 360">Xbox 360</option>
    <option value="Both">Both</option>
  </select>

  Game Category:  
  <select name="game_category">
    <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
    <option value="PSN">PSN</option>
    <option value="Arcade">Arcade</option>
    <option value="Arcade">DLC</option>
  </select>

  Game Type:  
  <select name="game_type">
    <option value="Action">Action</option>
    <option value="Action RPG">Action RPG</option>
    <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
    <option value="Board">Board</option>
    <option value="Card">Card</option>
    <option value="Casino">Casino</option>
    <option value="Educational">Educational</option>
    <option value="Fighting">Fighting</option>
    <option value="Flight">Flight</option>
    <option value="Game Show">Game Show</option>
    <option value="Hunting">Hunting</option>
    <option value="Music">Music</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="Pinball">Pinball</option>
    <option value="Platformer">Platformer</option>
    <option value="Puzzle">Puzzle</option>
    <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
    <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
    <option value="Shooter">Shooter</option>
    <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="Strategy">Strategy</option>
    <option value="Virtual Pet">Virtual Pet</option>
  </select>



 Trophy Totals:</p> 

 Bronze:  <input name="brinze_ttl" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" />
 <br/>
Silver:  <input name="Silver Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Gold:  <input name="Gold Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Platinum:  <input name="Platinum Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Hidden:  <input name="Hidden Total" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" /><br/>
Xbox Pts.:  <input name="Xbox Pts Total" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" /><br/>



</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Trophies:</p>
Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[0]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[0]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[0]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[0]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[1]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[1]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[1]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[1]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[2]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[2]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[2]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[2]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[3]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[3]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[3]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[3]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[4]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[4]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[4]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[4]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>

Trophy Name:    <input name="tr_name[5]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Descripton:     <input name="tr_desc[5]" type="text" size="50" maxlength="255" /><br/>
Trophy Color:   <select name="tr_color[5]">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="Hidden">Hidden</option>
</select>
Points: <input name="tr_ach_value[5]" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" /><p></p>


<input name="submit" type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: "I probably have multiple errors in this code"? First you must find them. Enable error reporting.

Comment: You assume each query succeeds. At bare minimum each query call should be done like this: `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())`.

Comment: I think you're right about it being with the form. It doesn't look like you actually have any form elements named trophy so `$_POST['trophy']` isn't getting anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the `$_POST` parameters in your query in `{}`'s, like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO games (game_name, release_date, game_category, game_type, game_console)
VALUES
('{$_POST['game_name']}', '{$_POST['release_date']}', '{$_POST['game_category']}', '{$_POST['game_type']}', '{$_POST['game_console']}')";
```

What others have said about SQL injection is also true. You should, at the very least, be escaping these strings using `mysql_real_escape_string` but using PDO or prepared statements is probably a good idea too.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is susceptible to SQL injection. You have to escape the parameters e.g. with mysql_real_escape_string. Also I can recommend the PDO database interface which is DBMS independent and have safer methods.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Thanks for the tip August!  I'll fix that before it goes live.

Answer (score 1):

SQL trouble?  Easy solution - echo $sql and run it in your SQL editor to see if it's valid.  I've tracked down more SQL problems that way.

Answer (score 1):

Enable error reporting (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) too see what errors there are in your code.

Just to warn you, check for sql injections http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on this but maybe try swapping your foreach statement out with:

```
for (i = 0; i <=5; i++)
{
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO trophies (game_name, tr_name, tr_description, tr_color, tr_ach_value) VALUES ('".$_POST['game_name']."', '".$_POST['tr_name'][i]."', '".$_POST['tr_desc'][i]."', '".$_POST['tr_color'][i]."', '".$_POST['tr_arch_value'][i]."')";
    mysql_query($sql3);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

First it doesn't look like you're actually passing in the right values to connection. Instead of:

```
$con = mysql_connect("hostname","username","password");
```

you should do something like

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","some password");
```

Same thing for your database; you want the actual name of your database instead of `dbname` unless of course that is really the name of your database.

Also, be careful of how you're doing your INSERTS and such. You're not escaping any of the values so you're susceptible to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Am I missing something, or did you change nothing except the parameters that he probably masked?

Comment: if I was to guess D. Seckler simply put in those values to not use the real ones he has in actual code.  There's nothing wrong with the syntax.

Comment: With my host, I have to use the host name they give me instead of localhost.  I've done that in the past with success.  What would "root" be?  I thought the username of the db went there.

Comment: "when I hit submit nothing happened". Something happened when you hit submit. What was it? i.e. the form was posted to the url but the resulting page was blank, or the resulting page indicated that the record was inserted but it was not inserted into the db. Also, head the warning about sql injection.

Comment: Sorry I jumped to answer the question too quickly and didn't think about how you probably went through and swapped everything out to their generic values I thought maybe you just copied and pasted from a tutorial and didn't think to change the values. I just through root in there because thats a typical username at least for linux installs.

Comment: Rob, When I hit submit the form just stayed on the page and nothing was added to the db.

Comment: @D. Seckler: root is the default username that ships with mysql, equivalent to 'sa' in the SQL Server world. far too many people never bother setting up seperate accounts for web-facing systems and just run everything as the DB's superuser.

Comment: "root" would be the big boy username.  The master and commander.  The Alpha.  King of kings.  Or more simply: the default administrator for mysql.